# How to calculate the height and width of an isometric rectangle/square

Tags: math, drawing, trigonometry, tiles, isometric

I'm writing an isometric tile game.  Each tile is twice as wide as it is tall (w:h = 2:1).  All tiles in a map are the same size and their width and heights are known (TileWidth and TileHeight).

There can be any number of columns (>0) and rows (>0).

I'm struggling to come up with a formula to calculate the width and height of the fully drawn map. This needs to be the distance from the very top to the very bottom and the extreme left to the extreme right. As the number of columns and rows can vary (and thus the map is not always a perfect diamond) it's proving very hard!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! There's a not-too-obvious answer but it's easy to calculate:

Let's call the row axis "r" and the column axis "c", and consider the first picture, where the extent along the r axis is 5 and the extent along the c axis is 3.

The unit increment along the r axis, relative to the drawing plane, is at angle +30 = (cos 30°, sin 30°) = (sqrt(3)/2, 0.5), and the unit increment along the c axis is at -30 = (cos 30°, -sin 30°) = (sqrt(3)/2, -0.5).

You need to consider the two diagonals of your isometric rectangle. In the first picture, those diagonals are D1 = [+5*U along the r axis and +3*U along the c axis] and D2 = [+5*U along the r axis and -3*U along the c axis], where U is the tile length in the isometric plane. When transformed into the drawing plane, this becomes D1 = ((5+3)*sqrt(3)/2*U, (5-3)/2*U) = (4*sqrt(3)*U, 1*U) and D2 = ((5-3)*sqrt(3)/2*U, (5+3)/2*U) = (sqrt(3)*U, 4*U). The screen width and height, therefore, are the maximum of the two extents = 4*sqrt(3)*U, 4*U.

This can be generalized: if there are Nr rows and Nc columns, and the tile length is U, the extent of the diagonals of the rectangle in the drawing plane are D1 = ((Nr+Nc)*sqrt(3)/2*U, (Nr-Nc)/2*U) and D2 = ((Nr-Nc)*sqrt(3)/2*U, (Nr+Nc)/2*U), and the screen width and height, therefore, are:

```
W = U*(Nr+Nc)*sqrt(3)/2
H = U*(Nr+Nc)/2
```

Answer (score 2):

The angles of the isometric projection are 60deg and 30deg. The actual width and height of a tile will be:

`Wiso = TileWidth * Cos(30) + TileHeight * Cos(60)`
`Hiso = TileWidth * Sin(30) + TileHeight * Sin(60)`

Now you can add multiply these numbers by the number of tiles per row and column to get the grid's size.

EDIT: looking at your images, it seems like the projection is not isometric (at least not what I learned in school), and the angles are 60deg to both sides, so replace the `Cos(60)` with `Cos(30)` and the `Sin(60)` with `Sin(30)`

Another way to look at it:

`Wgrid = TileWidth * Cos(30) * Ncols + TileHeight * Cos(30) * Nrows`
`Hgrid = TileWidth * Sin(30) * Ncols + TileHeight * Sin(30) * Nrows`

Comment: Thanks. They're not strictly isometric - they're dimetric (twice as wide as tall).

Answer (score 2):

If you start at the bottom and walk up the left side, you move up half the tile height for each column, then half the height for each row. Similarly if you start at the left and walk along the bottom edge, you move up half the tile width for each column, then half the width for each row.

So the width of the axis-aligned bounding box for the map is `(rows+columns)*TileWidth/2` and the height is `(rows+columns)*TileHeight/2`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use rotation equations as follows:

Suppose the tiles are not rotated, so the four corners have the following coordinates:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(w, 0, 0)
(0, h, 0)
(w, h, 0)
```

where

```
w = Number of Columns * Tile Width
h = Number of Rows * Tile Height
```

Now I suppose you have the projection matrix, so after applying it, you get 2D screen coordinates of the 4 3D points, and what you need to do is this:

1. Get the minimum x-coordinate of all the points (after projection).
2. Get the maximum x-coordinate of all the points (after projection).
3. Get the minimum y-coordinate of all the points (after projection).
4. Get the maximum y-coordinate of all the points (after projection).

Subtract 1 from 2, and you to get the width, and 3 from 4 to get the height.

Does that help?

Comment: isometric projection is not a rotation.

Comment: Ops, sorry, but that doesn't change the solution really. Rather than using the rotation matrix, he can use the projection matrix, then do the same calculation.

Comment: Blimey.  This is tricky.  I think my angle theta is 45 degrees but I don't really understand the matrix formulae written in the Wikipedia article.  I feel quite dumb (my background is not maths or computer science!).

Comment: OK, then can you please explain more about your game? What are you using for it? Game engine? DirectX, etc.? How are you defining the tiles? This way I can give you a specific answer.

Comment: It's a game engine written in REAL Studio.  The tiles are png images.  Here is the code I use to place the tiles on the screen: x = column * (Data.TileWidth/2) + (row * (TileWidth/2)) + Origin.X
         y = column * (TileHeight/2) - (row * (TileHeight/2)) + Origin.Y.  Where Origin is the start of the map (deals with scrolling) and x and y are the actual coordinates.

Comment: Garry, I can't really tell with the information provided; no angle, etc. I recommend you edit the question and mention that you are using REAL studio, and put the code in detail, this way others may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this with [Pythagoras' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

```
halfWidth = tileWidth / 2;
halfHeight = tileHeight / 2;
h = Math.sqrt((halfWidth * halfWidth ) * (halfHeight * halfHeight));
rowLength = rowSize * h;
colLength = colSize * h;
```

My maths is not great but `h` should be the length of one side of a tile so you can then multiply that by the number of tiles.

Comment: This works for calculating the width and height of the rectangle (and thus the hypotenuse of the triangle bisecting the map) but not the width of the map.